# How to sort NSMutableArray? Code review needed

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

Good evening.

This code works. It sorts an array of cards by both Suit and Card Value. It is also very much brute force. Can you recommend a better way? Does Objective-C help dealing with a situation where object being sorted itself has multiple fields, on which sorting depends?

```
-(void) sort: (NSMutableArray *) deck {        
    NSUInteger count = [deck count];

    Card *thisCard;
    Card *nextCard;

    int this;
    int next;

    BOOL stillSwapping = true;

    while (stillSwapping) {

        stillSwapping = false;

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            this = i;
            next = i+1;

            if (next < count) {

                thisCard = [deck objectAtIndex:this];
                nextCard = [deck objectAtIndex:next];

                if ([thisCard suit] > [nextCard suit]) {                        
                    [deck exchangeObjectAtIndex:this withObjectAtIndex:next];
                    stillSwapping = true;
                } 


                if ([thisCard suit] == [nextCard suit]) {
                    if ([thisCard value] > [nextCard value]) {
                        [deck exchangeObjectAtIndex:this withObjectAtIndex:next];
                        stillSwapping = true;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several options.

Perhaps the simplest is to define the method `-compare:` on `Card`, which returns an [`NSComparisonResult`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparisonResult). This is preferable if sorting by suit and value is the "standard" way to sort a `Card`. If you've done this, then your entire sorting method can be turned into

```
[deck sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

If you don't want to do this, you can use an array of [`NSSortDescriptor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/)s, one for suit and one for value.

```
[deck sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"suit" ascending:YES], [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"value"] ascending:YES], nil]];
```

If this doesn't work for whatever reason, you could try [`-sortUsingComparator:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-SW8)

```
[deck sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Card *obj1, Card *obj2) {
    int suit1 = [obj1 suit];
    int suit2 = [obj2 suit];
    if (suit1 > suit2) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if (suit1 < suit2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else {
        id value1 = [obj1 value];
        id value2 = [obj2 value];
        if (value1 > value2) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        } else if (value1 < value2) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        } else {
            return NSOrderedSame;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  I would recommend going w/the suggestion of implementing `compare:` on your class (using the code in the block for the comparison).